# Can't install gedit plugins on Linux Mint 12

Tags: linux, plugins, linux-mint, gedit

I'm trying to install for instance [this](https://github.com/jefferyto/gedit-control-your-tabs) plugin in gedit on Linux Mint 12 (Gnome 3). The gedit version is 3.2.3. According to the Gnome gedit plugins page, the following must hold for third party plugins:

> To install one of these, you need to download the files and put them in your ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/ directory (which may need to be created). They need to be in that exact directory; subdirectories are not scanned for plugins.

I have done exactly that, but no third-party plugin will appear in the plugins list. Does anyone have any advice? It would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61785/how-do-i-install-a-plugin-for-gedit-v3/61786#61786). Apparently one needs to

- Change the extension for the description file from .gedit-plugin to .plugin (which I did)
- In addition one must edit the header of this file from [Gedit plugin] to [Plugin]

The second point solved the problem for me, but this should be better documented by the gedit guys.

Answer (score 1):

patch in the form of deb package for ubuntu 11.10 works for me.
the deb is available at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/i386/gedit-latex-plugin/3.3.1-1~oneiric1
and download and install gedit-latex-plugin_3.3.1-1~oneiric1_all.deb